# Не работает метод проверки видимости элемента checkVisibility()

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

Всем привет! есть задача проверить видимость элемента на странице сайта, в консоли браузера нашёл подходящий метод js checkVisibility() который возвращает bool, ниже скрин работы метода в консоли

[image: Проверка работы метода в консоли браузера]

Пытаюсь из C# таким образом вызвать этот метод, постоянно выходит ошибка что checkVisibility  не функция. Элемент определяется корректно, проверено на других методах js.

```
IWebElement element = GetEl(By.XPath($"(//div[text() = 'Обновить'])[1]/../../..//button"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].checkVisibility();", element);
```

[image: Ошибка из Visual Studio]

Кто что может подсказать?

Comment: сделайте поиск элемента в JS, а не в C#, через аргументы элемент DOM вы не сможете передать https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284815/12888024, правда в JS наверное не через XPath удобней будет, а через CSS запрос `querySelector`.

Comment: `.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('ext-element-60526').checkVisibility();");`